# What sort of kebab is used with Chellow Kebab?

Tags: kebab, skewers

I came across the following picture

[image]

in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kebabs#Iran) the entire serving was being called Chellow Kebab without separately naming the Kebab Variety.

I would like to know the name of the Kebab as displayed in the picture and the recipe to make it

Comment: An alternative spelling is Chelo Kebab, which may help with Googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chelo (or Chellow) kebab refers to the entire dish which consists of the kebabs (usually 2), rice, and usually grilled tomatoes. Sometimes other accompaniments are included as well.

The most common types of kebabs used for this dish are koobideh (ground beef) and barg (ground lamb). It is sometimes served with one of each. There are exceptions and, though not as common, other types of kebab may be used.

If you perform a Google search for *Chelo kebab recipe* you will get tons of results. Most of the recipes include both the rice and the kebab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In case if my question was not quite clear (I do apologize for it), I am particularly interested in the one displayed in the picture

Comment: @Abhijit the picture includes both a saffron chicken kebab (jujeh kabab) and a meat kebab.  Without tasting it, there's really no way for anyone else to tell you whether it is lamb or beef just from the picture.

Comment: @Abhijit You *could* try a Google image search to see where the image came from and if there was a recipe included. If there wasn't, then sorry, you're out of luck, and the closest you'll get is a similar recipe.

Comment: @Didgeridrew: I am particuarly interested in the kebab which is along the center of the picture. Also I am more interested to know the name of the kebab and the recipe rather than whether its lamb or beaf.

Comment: @Abhijit Most likely it is barg kebab (made with ground lamb) or koobideh kebab (made with ground beef), as is in the answer. As per the comments from Didgeridrew and logophobe there is no way to tell for sure unless you can get a recipe for the dish in the picture.

Comment: Here is the link (http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschelo_Kabāb) where the picture is located. However, I am not able to translate. Performing a Google search using the spelling on that page, Tschelo Kebab only comes up with results for chelo kebab.